# python groupby statement only leaving aggregate fields

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
frame = frame2.groupby(['name1', 'name2', 'date', 'agID','figi', 'exch', 'figi', 'marketSector','name','fx_currency', 'id_type', 'id', 'currency']).agg({'call_agreed_amount' : 'sum' , 'pledge_current_market_value' : 'sum', 'pledge_quantity' : 'sum', 'pledge_adjusted_collateral_value' : 'sum', 'count' : 'count'})
print(frame.head())
for value in frame['call_currency']:
    doStuff()
```

In the code above, all columns exist before the groupby statement. After the groupby statement is executed, the `frame.head()` returns all of the same columns. My code fails at my for loop with a `KeyError` trying to access `frame['call_currency']`, which 100% exists in `frame`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After troubleshooting myself, I realized that python's groupby function returns a GroupBy object with a hierarchical index. The grouped columns were added as the index for the aggregate values. In order to fix this, I added `.reset_index()` to the end of my groupby statement.